# Rails: Why before_save on parent is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Job has many invoices:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices, :autosave => true
  before_save :set_outstanding_payments
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

When invoice is updated (`@invoice.update(...)`), job's `set_outstanding_payments` is called.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really astonished with this behavior since, as documentations said, autosaving is only triggered when the parent is saved.

The cause could be because having the `:autosave => true` declaration in your Job association with Invoice causes the child update to call **save** on the parent.

When the save is called on the parent, all save hooks are called. Even though, make sure you don't have any **before** or **after** update hooks in the `Invoice` model which messes with the parent.

For more information about the Autosave Association feature, please refer to this link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

I hope it helps somehow.

Comment: As far as I can see, the documentation states that saving the parent (the job) will save the associations (the invoices), but not vice versa. What am I missing?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Are you sure about not having any hooks on Invoice that messes with the parent ? What about the client code which calls the `@invoice.update` ? Let's dive more into it, to try to find the issue. I would be glad to help ;)

Comment: You were right! I had an `after_action` in my invoices controller that was updating the job. Thanks!